# Itemize too big

Tags: beamer, fontsize, itemize

I want all my bulletpoints to be square and same size. But when I use this command, the first item is bigger than the other two. Is there a way how I can change it to the size of the other bulletpoints? [image]

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\begin{block}{1. Introduction} 
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[square]
\begin {itemize}
\item \scriptsize {Problematic and Motivation}
\item \scriptsize{Literature review} 
\item \scriptsize{Contribution}
```

Comment: `\scriptsize {Problematic and Motivation}`  makes the rest of the document small just use `\scriptsize`  once before the list, with no `{}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Although the problem is obvious from your incomplete code snippet, please make it a habit to post snippets that are compilable.

Answer (score 3):

size commands do not take an argument so `\scriptsize {Problematic and Motivation}`  makes the rest of the document small. Your `{}` and the second and third `\scriptsize` do nothing.

Just use `\scriptsize`  once before the list, with no `{}`

```
\scriptsize
\begin {itemize}
\item Problematic and Motivation
\item Literature review
\item Contribution
```

Answer (score 2):

To change the size of your items, you could change the respective beamer fonts like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\begin{block}{1. Introduction} 
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[square]
\setbeamerfont{itemize item}{size=\scriptsize}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate body}{size=\scriptsize}
\begin{itemize}
\item Problematic and Motivation
\item Literature review
\item Contribution
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\end{frame}

    
\end{document}
```